# Transcendental entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

$f$ is a transcendental entire function $M(r)=\max_{|z|=r} |f|$
Then for any $0<\alpha<1$ we have the limit

$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{M(\alpha r)}{M(r)} =0$

Who can give some suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is transcendental, $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty} \frac{\log M(r)}{\log r} = \infty$. By the Hadamard three-circle theorem, $\log M(r)$ is a convex function of $\log r$.  For the rest of the argument, it is probably best to write $x=\log r$ and $g(x) = \log M(r) = \log M(e^x)$. Then $y=\log (\alpha r) =x + \log \alpha$, and by the Mean Value Theorem, $\log \frac{M(\alpha r)}{M(r)} = g(y) - g(x) = (\log \alpha) g'(\xi)$ with $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$. By convexity, $g'$ is an increasing function, so $g'(\xi) \ge g'(y) \to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$, so $\log \frac{M(\alpha r)}{M(r)} \to -\infty$ (since $\log \alpha<0$), proving the claim.